# Swagger redirecting to login when going from Production mode to Developer

Tags: magento2, api, developer-mode, production-mode, swagger

When I tried to set my production mode instance to developer mode I can not get swagger to load.

If I go to mystore.com/swagger it will redirect to the login page.

Deploy mode is set to developer. I also cleared the data in var/view_preprocessed and generated/ folders. Then cleared cache as well. I also restarted php-fpm and nginx.

I am on Magento 2.2.7

Still I can not get swagger to load.